# Calendar.setTime sets the wrong date

Tags: java, android, datetime

The code below sets the date to midnight on 7 June 2015. Why? My time zone is UTC-07:00

Greg

```
           Calendar HuntStart = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy K:mm a", Locale.US);
            try {
                HuntStart.setTime(sdf.parse("6/6/2015 12:00 PM"));//AllLists.get(position).HuntStart));
            }
            catch (ParseException ex) {

            }
```

Comment: be more specific...'midnight' Is it 12:00 P.M on 6/6/2015 or is it 12:00 P.M on 6/7/2015?

Comment: After HuntStart.setTime(sdf.parse("6/6/2015 12:00 PM")), if I call HuntStart.getTime() it returns 6/7/2015 00:00:00. I would expect HuntStart.getTime() to return 6/6/2015 12:00 PM

Comment: 12:00 PM is noon.  Midnight is 12:00 AM.

Comment: You're stating the obvious. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes form the hour letter you are using in your SimpleDateFormat constructor.

See the SimpleDateFormat JavaDoc [SimpleDateFormat javaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) :

K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)

You are using the letter **K** and the javadoc says that this option should be used with hour **(0-11)** so that you use **12** in your String.
I didn't look in the implementation of the class, but it's with no doubt a side-effect. You overlap the hour range allowed, so you go into the next day.
It's pitty that the constructor be so permissive. An IllegalArgumentException or like would be useful.

To conclude, you have 2 solutions.

if you want use the 12 hour as source String for parsing, your should use the **h** letter pattern in your constructor.
Like that :

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);
```

If you want to keep your hour pattern **K**, your should not use a String instance with 12 but **0** as input for the parse method
Like that :

```
    huntStart.setTime(sdf.parse("06/06/2015 00:00 PM"));// AllLists.get(position).HuntStart));
```

Comment: Thanks. I Realized this when I went to Joda because it threw an exception when passing 12:00 and using the K, as expected. I said it before and got a lot of down votes for it, but I'll say it again: DateTime and the Calendar object suck beyond belief in Java.

Comment: You are welcome.
DateTime is a JodaTime class. I think you refer to Date and Calendar.
I agree : Date and Calendar are not handy class indeed.
Most of developers know it.
On the new Date API document website, you can read "A long-standing bugbear of Java developers has been the inadequate support for the date and time use cases of ordinary developers."
Java 8 and the new API address most of drawbacks of Date class by inspiring from the JodaTime API.

Answer (score 1):

Gave up on Java Calendar and switched to Joda Time. The code below returns 2015-06-06T12:00:00.000-07:00 for HuntStart, as expected.

```
            DateTime HuntStart = new DateTime();
            DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("M/d/yyyy h:mm a");
            HuntStart = fmt.parseDateTime("6/6/2015 12:00 PM");
```

Comment: The interessting thing is: you can use the same pattern with `SimpleDateFormatter.`. The usage of *K* instead of *h* isn't correct for your date string.

Comment: Realized this when I went to Joda because it threw an exception. One more reason to not use Java datetime.

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code to update the calendar object instead of SimpleDateFormat

```
HuntStart.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.JUNE);
HuntStart.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,6);
HuntStart.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
HuntStart.set(Calendar.HOUR,12);
HuntStart.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
```

Comment: The actual code is pulling the time from AllLists.get(position).HuntStart, which is a String. I would rather not have to parse it.